# Virtual Classes having more size

Tags: c++, oop, virtual-inheritance

```
class abstract 
{double abs; };

class A : virtual public abstract
{ double var; };

class B : virtual public abstract
{ double var; };

class derived : public A, public B
{ double der; };
```

> sizeof(abstract) = 8
>
> sizeof(A) = 24
>
> sizeof(B) = 24
>
> sizeof(derived) = 48

Why does this happen?

(Note: On the contrary without the `virtual` classes the sizes returned are 8, 16, 16, 40 respectively. )

Comment: **Probably** (but it's implementation defined) they're to keep track (point to) virtual base class. See also [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737847/multiple-inheritance-size-of-class-for-virtual-pointers/9737936#9737936).

Answer (score 0):

It requires the type to store more information to facilitate virtual behavior.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.

Comment: Sorry, there is no type information in any instance! And virtual functions have nothing to do with rtti!

Comment: It depends on the compiler implementation, but it will store a pointer back to the vtable, and that is "more information".